URL Button not working in production
I have this button I created in a sandbox:

/lightning/o/Correction__c/new?&defaultFieldValues=
Audit_Finding__c={!URLENCODE(Audit_Finding__c.Id)},
Origination__c={!IF(TEXT(Audit_Finding__c.Scope__c) != "Corporate", TEXT(Audit_Finding__c.Origination__c), null)},
Origination_Entity__c={!IF(TEXT(Audit_Finding__c.Scope__c) != "Corporate", TEXT(Audit_Finding__c.Origination_Entity__c), null)},
Title__c={!Audit_Finding__c.Title__c}

This is working fine when i click my button i have the fields prefiled:

However I deployed in production my fields are not filled automatically.
I checked the profiles rights on the fields I'm using in the URL and I have access to them (read and edit).
The button is the same, fields are the same (I checked them One by one). I just pushed again the layout aswell.
Here is what I have in production:

What Am I missing? I notice a difference between the 'layout' of the pop-up but the object layout is the same :/
Also in my sandboxe the url i got after clicking is a modified url:
https://XXXXSandboxe/lightning/o/Correction__c/new?count=2&backgroundContext=%2Fone%2Fone.app%23eyJjb21wb25lbnREZWYiOiJvbmU6YWxvaGFQYWdlIiwiYXR0cmlidXRlcyI6eyJhZGRyZXNzIjoiL3NlcnZsZXQvc2VydmxldC5JbnRlZ3JhdGlvbj9saWQ9MDBiN2EwMDAwMDNiTlZ0JmVpZD1hMTA3YTAwMDAwQkU0NktBQVQmaWM9MSZ3cmFwTWFzc0FjdGlvbj0xJmxpbmtUb2tlbj1WbXBGUFN4TmFrRjVUa013ZDA1cE1IZE5WbEY0VGtSdmVFMTZiM2ROUXpRMVRucE9ZU3h1VEhCU2QxWnRUR2xFV0UwMlVuY3hlRmRwWTB0bVoyZHZMVzU1WVd4TFJqY3hjMnA2YmtSdmFqQTBQU3haVjFwclRVZEthQSUzRCUzRCZ1c2UzMDdyZWRpcmVjdD10cnVlIiwicG9zdFBhcmFtZXRlcnMiOnsiaWRzIjpbXX19LCJzdGF0ZSI6e319.
In my production the URL doesn't seems to be interpretated correclty as the URL is not modified:
https://XXXXPROD/lightning/o/Correction__c/new?defaultFieldValues=Audit_Finding__c%3Da103V000000TEnO%2COrigination__c%3DManufacturing%20Site%2COrigination_Entity__c%3Dzzzzz%2CTitle__c%3DTraining%20-%20Local%20zzzz%20-%20Test&count=1
If any of you has an idea I feel very dumb to be stuck on that.
Thanks.

Are you certain that you're pressing the right button in Prod? What did you name the button? Something obvious, or just "New"? Also, not sure if it would help or why it would make a difference between Sandbox & Prod, but try removing the whitespace in the URL. You have a spacebar between defaultFieldValues= and the rest of the string, for example. (defaultFieldValues= Audit_Finding__c)

@MorganMarchese Thanks for the answer.
I'm certain the button is the same it has a specific name: 'new correction from finding' and when i'm modifying the button the URL change accordingly.
I did try to remove the space but it's still not working. I also updated my question.

Am I correct that in Sandbox the New Record screen is opening in full screen but in Production the New Record screen is opening as a modal?

the backgroundContext is just the lightning way of doing the Classic retURL and was probably added by Lightning based on the way you were testing. In sandbox is this a copy-paste typo ...?&defaultFieldValues=...?  You have ?& which is not correct. You are also URLENCODEing things that don't need it - like IDs, and those that do, like text fields

@MorganMarchese they are both opening in modals (sorry for the delayed answer)

@cropredy
The links posted is just what is in the URL After i click the button.
I tryed to remove '?&' or replace it just with '?' and the URLENCODE.
I still have the same behavior

Here to answer my own question:
I still don't know why it is happening but i found a workaround.
I added "&nooverride=true" at the start of my button and now it is working in production.
Like this => "/lightning/o/Correction__c/new?&nooverride=true&defaultFieldValues=" Etc...
Have a good day
